# ZSH prompt disappears after typing too much

Tags: zsh, prompt

When I type for too long with zsh, the prompt disappears and it leaves a single character on the same line as the rest of what I was typing, the rest goes to a new line below it. Not sure how to tell if this is a `COLUMNS` issue or something completely different.

The `.zshrc` for the root user seems to work fine, with the Right Prompt going away once the input is long enough, and doesn't glitch out. My personal one also seems to fix itself once shifted to and from the master/stack in my window manager (AwesomeWM, not sure if that is affecting it)

Pictures:
ROOT PS1: [image: https://imgur.com/a/pfWZB7x]

PERSONAL PS1: [image: https://imgur.com/lJMyw4k]

Files:
ROOT .zshrc: https://paste.gnome.org/pff0tkabw

Personal .zshrc: https://paste.gnome.org/pxy8cfrcu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing most of your `.zshrc` file has been lifted from an older, or somebody else's, `.bashrc` file, as there are a number of things in it that would be done differently in `zsh` compared to `bash`.

Your current prompt is set with

```bsh
PS1='[${GREEN}%n${NC}@${GREEN}%m${NC}:${CYAN}%1~${NC}]%(?,,[${RED}%?${NC}])$(git_status)$ '
```

where `$GREEN` etc. are control sequences produced by `tput`.

This has the issue that the shell will have a hard time figuring out how wide the prompt is, since you're using your own escape sequences for coloring instead of using the standard way of doing it in `zsh`.

I would suggest you ditch your `$GREEN` etc. variable and instead use

```bsh
PS1='[%F{green}%n%f@%F{green}%m%f:%F{cyan}%1~%f]%(?,,[%F{red}%?%f])$(git_status)$ '
```

Each `%F{colorname}` sets the foreground color to `colorname` and each `%f` stops using that color.

To properly use your own escape sequences, each such sequence should be enclosed in `%{...%}`, so that the shell knows that it will take no space in the prompt (the root user's initialization file does this, but in a roundabout way):

```bsh
PS1='[%{${GREEN}%}%n%{${NC}%}@%{${GREEN}%}%m%{${NC}%}:%{${CYAN}%}%1~%{${NC}%}]%(?,,[%{${RED}%}%?%{${NC}%}])$(git_status)$ '
```

Note that this also means that the output from your `git_status` shell function, which contains color codes, needs to be updated.

Read the section entitled "EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES" in the `zshmisc` manual.

Comment: Thank you, will do!